# Can I tell Optaplanner (with constraint streams) not to recalculate join if it doesn't depend on planning variable?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I'm using `fromUniquePair​(Class<A> fromClass, BiJoiner<A,​A> joiner)` at the start of my constraint stream. The fromClass is a planning entity, representing a time slot. I need a stream of all pairs of time slots that overlap, to later check that their planning variables don't conflict. The time slot doesn't move in time based on any planning variable, so the result of this fromUniquePair join doesn't change while optimising.

However, whenever a planning variable changes, the time slot gets compared to all other time slots to see if a pair needs to be added or removed from the stream. This is unnecessary because the result of this joiner doesn't depend on the planning variables in any way. I think the majority of time is spent on doing just this, as it needs to check thousands of other time slots every time a planning variable gets changed, while it only needs to do a few quick checks on the planning variable itself.

Is there a way to tell Optaplanner not to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for here can be compared to the property reactivity feature in Drools. Unfortunately, Constraint Streams does not support that, nor is there a way it ever could - Constraint Streams can not see inside the filter lambdas or method references, and therefore it does not know which fields you access. This is a price we pay for a better abstraction.

I do not think `flattenLast()` will do anything in this regard. The entity you do `from(...)` on will still be reevaluated every time it is changed, and then all the flattened data would be re-evaluated too. That said, maybe I have misunderstood your intentions and if you update your original question with additional information, I'll reconsider.

Comment: At least from the user's perspective, it would be relatively straightforward to give the joiners an optional extra argument where you can explicitly say which planning variables the join depends on. The default value would be all planning variables, as it is now. Of course I don't know how much work the implementation would be.

Comment: I'm going to explain the part about the flattenLast in another question, it's not really related to this one, just an alternative solution I had in mind to my problem. I shouldn't have put it in this question really.

Comment: Wrt. the extra argument - that is one part of what we'd need to have. The other thing'd have to be some kind of instrumentation of your entities, to know which of the fields actually changed. (Just like Drools property reactivity does.) And we would have to make sure that the extra arguments users provide match what we read and instrument in the code. That'd be a massive increase in complexity, possibly error-prone for the users. Although I have to admit that the perf benefits would probably be worth it.

Comment: Property reactive is exteremly maintenance unfriendly. A junior developer that needs to modify your code in a year from now, will forgot to properly pass the property reactive fields. But we could support it, if it's clearly indicated in the API methods called?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, splitting up the entity class into a class that just holds the problem facts and one that just holds the planning variables works too:

For example, split up

```
@PlanningEntity
class Foo {
   Bar bar1;
   Ber ber1;
   Bur bur1;
   @PlanningVariable Bor bor1;
}
```

into

```
class Foo {
   Bar bar1;
   Ber ber1;
   Bur bur1;
}
@PlanningEntity
class FooAssignment {
   Foo foo;
   @PlanningVariable Bor bor1;
}
```

This is also more planning cloning friendly. But it doesn't fit for all cases.