# Can I explicitly tell Optaplanner (with constraint streams) that a certain constraint stream depends on a certain entity?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

My planning entities represent time slots. I need a stream of all pairs of time slots that overlap, to later check that their planning variables don't conflict. The time slot doesn't move in time based on any planning variable, so the pairs I need don't change while optimising.

If I use a filtering join, whenever a planning variable changes, the time slot gets compared to all other time slots to see if a pair needs to be added or removed from the stream. As a more performant alternative, I tried to use my already-existing list of overlapping time slots, and use flattenLast to insert the resulting list into my stream:

```
return constraintFactory.from(TimeSlot.class)
  .groupBy(
    (timeSlot) -> timeSlot,
    (timeSlot) -> timeSlot.getOverlappingTimeSlots()
  )
  .flattenLast(Function.identity())
  .impact(...)
```

This however results in the following error message about a score corruption:

> Maybe a score constraint doesn't select all the entities it depends on, but finds some through a reference in a selected entity. This corrupts incremental score calculation, because the constraint is not re-evaluated if such a non-selected entity changes.

So clearly, Optaplanner does not check to see whether the results of flattenLast are planning entities that need to be "selected". Is there a way to tell Optaplanner so? To tell it to "select the entities", without having to calculate them using a costly join?

Comment: This is the alternative I first described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68005066/can-i-tell-optaplanner-with-constraint-streams-not-to-recalculate-join-if-it-d, but I decided to make it a separate question as I'm not really asking the same thing...

Comment: I just realised what I think is the correct solution: make a PlanningEntity named TimeSlotPair and give it shadow variables that refer to my planning variables. Create a TimeSlotPair class for every pair of TimeSlots that overlap. That way, changing a TimeSlot causes a change in the corresponding TimeSlotPairs and as such causes Optaplanner to recalculate my constraint stream...

Comment: If this solves your problem, I do not have anything else to add. If you post this as an answer, I will upvote it. The more generic answer to the question is: "No, we do not support anything like that out of the box, unless..." followed by what you just proposed. But it is an interesting thing to consider for future development of CS - having possibly massive joins that never change is a time sink.